# Manage 'MethodNotAllowedHttpException ' in RESTful APIs using Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, exception, laravel-5.3

I am new to laravel and want to handle exception if a user hits a urls by using wrong HTTP method. I want to send user response in json but code is not working, sometimes it gives blanks page. Below is my code:

Handler.php

```
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {

        if ($exception instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Bad Request.'], 404);
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {

        if (basename(str_replace('\\', '/', get_class($exception))) == 'MethodNotAllowedHttpException') {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Bad Request.'], 404);        
        }
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```